# Cannot Convert Zero to int32 from textbox

Tags: c#, validation

I have the following code to do a some very simple validation for a textbox

```
    if(txtInStock.Text.Length == 0)
        txtInStock.Text = Convert.ToString(0);

    if (txtInStock.Text.Length == 0)
        txtOnOrder.Text = Convert.ToString(0);

    int inStockAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtInStock.Text);
    int onOrderAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtOnOrder.Text);
```

This works fine when Text != 0 , but when Text == 0 I get a FormatException saying the string is not of the proper format. How can I correct this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
if (txtInStock.Text.Length == 0)
    txtOnOrder.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
```

You're checking the length of one text box and setting the text of another. Change it to this:

```
if (txtOnOrder.Text.Length == 0)
    txtOnOrder.Text = Convert.ToString(0);
```

Also, is there a reason you're using `Convert.ToString(0)` instead of just `"0"`? I don't particularly recommend using this approach for data validation, but this should correct the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As you can't be sure the user of your textbox will write a correct integer, I would recommend to use [Int32.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/f02979c7.aspx)  instead of Convert.ToInt32. Thus, you'll be able to easily handle the error cases.

Answer (score 1):

Would this code do?

```
    if(txtInStock.Text.Length == 0)
        txtInStock.Text = "0";

    if (txtInStock.Text.Length == 0)
        txtOnOrder.Text = "0";

    int inStockAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtInStock.Text);
    int onOrderAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtOnOrder.Text);
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: BTW there is no need for two conditionals, as they are checking the same condition.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple way to handle an empty textbox

```
if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( txtInStock.Text ))
    txtInStock.Text = "0";

if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( txtOnOrder.Text ))
    txtOnOrder.Text = "0";

int inStockAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtInStock.Text);
int onOrderAmt = Convert.ToInt32(txtOnOrder.Text);
```

I would also save the textbox values to temp variables and then do the comparisions unless if you wanted to force a 0 in the textbox when it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

int inStockAmt = Convert.ToInt32(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtInStock.Text) ? 0 : int.Parse(txtInStock.Text));